# how can i use restful api (returns json) in jsp pages

Tags: json, jsp, rest, web

whats the cool way to use restful api (returns json) in jsp pages, I understand there are lot of ways but which one should be good?

Answer (score 1):

None, really: if you need JSON, return JSON, and use a framework for the busywork.

If you absolutely must, I'd do as much work as possible in Java, like setting the response header, transform things into JavaScript-safe strings, and so on, and use JSP *only* for the presentation.

That said, I see almost zero benefit to handling any of it in JSP when you can write transformed data directly from Java with essentially zero effort using any of a number of libraries.

Knowing *why* you want to use JSP might make it easier to answer what the "best" way is *in your particular circumstance*: "best" here has an upper bound of "don't do it in JSP in the first place".

Comment: Thanks Dave, I have a application which has 2 apps one is functional app which exposes rest with json and the second one is UI app which is supposed to access rest app and render contents for users to view. My rest api is built on SPring and now trying to find a framework for UI app.

Comment: I don't really see why you need to create JSON in JSP, then--you need to *consume* JSON, which is the opposite, or *send* JSON, which you should do with either a client-side framework, or by making the REST calls based on form data on the server side.